# What happens closed Queue review audits which get marked to close?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I recently started a reviews in the Closed Queue. I came across an audit which I Failed.
[Xcode 9.3 Playground - diagnosticd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591847/xcode-9-3-playground-diagnosticd)

This question is most definitely too broad, and probably belongs in a different community.

So despite failing the audit.  I've gone to the question and flagged it to be closed for real.

What happens to this question now, seeing as it was previously an audit, and now that it's legitimately marked to be closed,

will voting to close this automatically remove it from being eligible for being an audit?

If not it might be a good idea to refine the audit selection process to avoid these types of questions, because logically, If an audit for close vote, has a vote to close on it, that would put it into the queue, so if it is still an audit that wouldn't that be a bug?

**Feature-Request**

If an audit has a vote to close remove it from the list of potential audits. While close vote is active.

If an audit is frequently voted for close (close votes/totalViews) > threashold || (close votes/ time since created) > threashold
remove the audit permanently from audits.

This will help filter bad audit, because the community views the questions ambiguously on some type of way

Comment: I know downvoting would disqualify it, but i'm not sure about a close vote that may or may not eventually result in a closure but hasn't yet.

Comment: @KevinB would downvoting it once disqualify it, Or would it have to go into negatives.  Logically, If an audit for close vote, has a vote to close on it, that would put it into the queue, so if it is still an audit wouldn;t that be considered a bug?

Comment: It would certainly at the very least be weird. I would assume that a close vote takes it out of the queue, but i haven't seen that specified anywhere.

Comment: Interesting, hopefully this gets question get's some attention and we can get this resolved

Comment: So far [at least 6 people have failed the audit.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49591847/timeline), but 5 passed it.

Comment: Luckily I didn't get a ban on it, (I'm sure It counted toward me getting one next time), but if those 6 people did fail it, hopefully someone will lift their ban

Comment: @KevinB  I probably should have skipped it, considered I knew it had 12 upvotes at the time.  And I know How unreliable the audit's are (I've learned my lessons in triage)  I'm more wondering if it's still an audit

Comment: at this point it shouldn't be, it's been downvoted and close voted. One of the two surely disqualified it. I'm not sure i agree with it needing to be closed, but i'm not too familiar with what's normal in those tags. but in either case i think it's a tricky audit. You could fail it even if you're paying attention.

Comment: @pnuts I’ve edited the feature request to be more clear